# $[0,1]$ is commonly called the unit interval - is there a similar term for $[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology

The interval $[0, 1]$ is commonly called the '[unit interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_interval)'. Is there something similar for $[-1, 1]$? Like a pre-defined name.

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: I would say *centered unit* interval for $[-\frac12,\frac12]$. One might risk *centered two-units* interval or *symmetrized unit* interval, but this doesn't sound convincing. Maybe *ambiunit* interval ? (neologism)

Comment: You could call it $D^1$ the one-dimensional disc: $D^1:=\{x\in\Bbb{R}:\lvert{x}\rvert\leq1\}$, but I doubt that's the kind of name you're looking for.

Comment: You can call it of closed interval centered at 0 with length 2.

Comment: If the context makes it clear that we're talking about subsets of $\mathbb R$, one can just refer to it as the closed unit ball. That does sound somewhat awkward, though.

Comment: @LoganToll: I prefer "closed unit ball in $\mathbb R$" and not "disk" and certainly not "disc".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the closed unit ball of $\mathbb{R}$ in its usual absolute value norm.

In any normed space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$, we have a closed unit ball (or disk) $$D=\{x \in X: \|x\| \le 1\}$$ and a unit sphere

$$S=\{x \in X: \|x\|=1\}$$ The unit sphere in the reals is $\{-1,1\}$ of course, the boundary of the unit ball $[-1,1]$.

They often get indexed by their dimension $n$ if it is finite, so  $D^1$ and $S^0$ in the above case. $\partial D^n = S^{n-1}$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Personally speaking, I have never found a particular definition for intervals of the form $[a,b]$ in general. I believe that the reason of that is that any closed interval is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and then it shares the same topological properties of $[0,1]$.

Any pair of closed intervals $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ are homeomorphic, for any choice of $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$. In fact the function $f:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ defined as 
$$f(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}(d-c)+c$$
is a possible homeomorphism.

By taking $c=0$ and $d=1$, you find an explicit homeomorphism between $[a,b]$ and $[0,1]$.

Also, the unit interval appears in more contexts than a general closed interval. For instance in algebraic topology an homotopy is parametrised by $[0,1]$. Another example comes from probability theory. The probability in measure by a real number in the unit interval $[0,1]$. So it makes sense that $[0,1]$ has a privileged role and has an own definition.